# JUnit & EasyMock

Tags: junit4, easymock

Is it possible to mock a class that is instantiated in the class I am unit testing?

```
class ClassToTest {
    public String methodToTest(object a, object b, object c) {
        //Do Lots of cool stuff here
        SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
        someOtherClass.doMoreCoolStuff(a, b, c, this);
        //Do even more cool stuff to "this" as it was updated by someOtherClass
}
```

I want to mock the SomeOtherClass that will be used int ClassToTest. I am using EasyMock and I can't seem to get it to compile. Any ideas? Am I going about this wrong? Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you can mock that class unless you use very obscure Java black magic, By design, you should avoid instantiate classes like that and instead you should associate classes so they would be less coupled. When you move to the association, then you are able to mock Objects around. In your case, you could treat your instantiated classes and method call as a private call whithin the method which then you don't mock it and just test as part of methodToTest test.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to get the mock in there.  This is all part of testing.  When you find something like this, and you say "I can't test that" then you need to refactor the code so you can test.  It is this refactoring that will slowly turn weird and strange designs into beautiful art.  (too deep?)

For example:

```
interface Factory {
    public SomeOtherClass create();
}

class ClassToTest {
    Factory factory;
    public void setFactory( Factory factory ) { this.factory = factory }

    public String methodToTest(object a, object b, object c) {
        //Do Lots of cool stuff here
        SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = factory.create();
        someOtherClass.doMoreCoolStuff(a, b, c, this);
        //Do even more cool stuff to "this" as it was updated by someOtherClass
}
```

A test would be something like this:

```
public void test() {
    SomeOtherClass mock = EasyMock.create( SomeOtherClass.class );
    Factory factory = EasyMock.create( Factory.class );

    ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest();
    test.setFactory( factory );

    expect(factory.create()).andReturn(mock);

    // can now test mock interaction

    replay(mock,factory);
    test.methodToTest(a,b,c);
    verify(mock,factory);

}
```

There are many ways to do this.  The point is to make your code testable.  There have been so many times I find myself needing a method for some class I wrote only to find it's already there because I needed it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Powermock.

```
SomeOtherClass soc=EasyMock.createNiceMock(SomeOtherClass.java);
Powermock.expectNew(SomeOtherClass.java).andReturn(soc).anyTimes();
```

`expectNew()` expects `'new'` invocation on that Particular class and returns the object that we want to return,which in our case must be a mocked object, so that the mock is injected whenever new is invoked on the specific class.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!